# How to make a desk grommet without a lathe?

Tags: tools

I have a walnut desk that now requires a 2" walnut grommet (since I cut the hole in the desk before realizing that walnut grommets are only for sale in 1 3/4" size)....so I need to make my own.

Pretty simple if I had a lathe to turn it on but that's not the case. Does anyone have an idea of how to create a 1/2" lip on a round wood plug that would be required for a desk grommet?

Comment: If you are good enough at eyeballing stuff, you can use a belt sander. There are jigs available to help shape round objects with a sander. Honestly, I'd be inclined to see if there are decent plastic grommets you can buy if wood isn't working out. Alternatively, you might be able to cobble something up with a holesaw and then clearing the centre with forstner bits.

Comment: 2" in walnut (and easy-working wood) and you just need one? I'd be inclined to just make this manually myself, you'd be started work after drawing circles with a compass before you'd even done the setup for it with e.g. a router.

Answer (score 2):

A few minutes after writing my Comment it occurred to me that although it would be easy enough to do this manually using hand tools the simplest method to make one of these is not to cut a lip at all but to use build-up construction.

You just need two small pucks of walnut, one the major diameter and the other the minor diameter (2"?). Glue the smaller one dead centre to the underside of the larger one and you're essentially done, except for any final sanding you want to do before finish goes on.

The whole process not including waiting for glue to dry should be about 15-30 minutes depending on the tools available and the walnut stock you have on hand. And if you use superglue/CA or hot-melt glue you don't even need to factor in glue drying time.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be to use two hole saws.  A large one with an inside diameter of about 2.5 inches, and a smaller one with an inside diameter of about 2 inches.  Drill about 2/3 of the way through with the smaller one, then drill all the way through with the larger one.  Then use a small handsaw to cut through the annulus, rotating the piece repeatedly as you cut through.  If you have a drill press you can use the hole saws without the center pilot if you don't want a small hole in the center.